# Developer Mode in iOS returns altitude as 0

Tags: ios, gps, gpx

I really hope you are a genius and that you can resolve the following issue :

My fake gps  location for iPhone and iPad works but when testing it - running in developer mode - it gives constant 0 as an altitude, that of course can't be good.

So now the question, can this be solved?

I know that only a real genius can solve this so surprise me ;)

Heather

Comment: Are you using the simulator?  If so, that will not report location.  If you're using Wi-Fi, that will not report altitude correctly.

Comment: what u want ? your question is not clear ? you are running in developer mode where? in real device or simulator ? explain your question properly plz